# installing typings require failed in macOSX

Tags: macos, ionic-framework, npm, require, pouchdb

I following a tutorial to 'use PouchDB for localStorage in ionic' and the author says i need run this command:

```
typings install require --ambient --save
```

i know in version 1.0 of typings, ambient changed to global but when i run this command i get an error:

```
sudo typings install require --global --save
typings ERR! message Unable to find "require" ("npm") in the registry. Did you want to try searching another source? Also, if you want contribute these typings, please help us: https://github.com/typings/registry
typings ERR! caused by https://api.typings.org/entries/npm/require/versions/latest responded with 404, expected it to equal 200

typings ERR! cwd /Users/userName/Desktop/ionic-projects/ionic2-tutorial-pouchdb
typings ERR! system Darwin 15.4.0
typings ERR! command "/usr/local/bin/node" "/usr/local/bin/typings" "install" "require" "--global" "--save"
typings ERR! node -v v4.4.4
typings ERR! typings -v 1.0.4

typings ERR! If you need help, you may report this error at:
typings ERR!   <https://github.com/typings/typings/issues>
```

thanks

Comment: Link to tutorial ?

Comment: @PrashantGhimire http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-ionic-2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I had exactly the same issue on windows.
try

```
typings install env~requirejs --global --save
```

I also submitted a [Issue](https://github.com/typings/typings/issues/533) at typings and they said I should try the following

```
typings install -SG dt~require
```

and if you get the following:

```
require
└── (No dependencies)
```

It means it has already bean installed

Comment: yes, I'm submitted too, and they said i should use that command you wrote.  thanks