# Typescript can't find 'require', setting up pouchdb with Ionic2

Tags: angularjs, typescript, ionic-framework, pouchdb

I'm also trying to follow the Tutorial **[How To Use PouchDB + SQLite For Local Storage In Ionic 2](http://gonehybrid.com/how-to-use-pouchdb-sqlite-for-local-storage-in-ionic-2/)**, which seems a good entry point for using pouchdb with Angular 2 / Ionic 2. My OS is OSx

After getting able to install typings 'require' `ionic serve` throws:

`TypeScript error: (...) Error TS2304: Cannot find name 'require'.`

I followed the [**installing typings require failed in macOSX**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37309865/installing-typings-require-failed-in-macosx) and [**Install Typings require for Ionic2 application**](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37444238/install-typings-require-for-ionic2-application) threads but it didn't help me. (beside of a better understanding of 'TypeScript')

the require files are under:

```
/ionic2-tutorial-pouchdb/typings/globals/require
```

any Ideas? The tutorial about 'install require' doesn't work for me.

thx Pitt

Comment: Thanks to @devid-farinelli for improving my post...

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that you have a line of code like:

```
let PouchDB = require('pouchdb');
```

You do not need to use require for importing into Angular2. Instead you should use import like this:

```
import PouchDB from 'pouchdb';
```

[Reference from one of the GitHub issues on the PouchDB GitHub account](https://github.com/nolanlawson/pouchdb-find/issues/201#issuecomment-232391450)

The link you provided also uses import rather than require. Also in newer versions of typescript, Typings have been replaced with @Types.